# Confusion in NumberSize function

Tags: c

I have created a function that will compare the numbers in a linked list to determine which number is the smallest and which number is the largest.  I know that `FirstNumber = determine->newNum;` points to the current number in the list.

How would I call for `SecondNuumber = ?;` to get the next number in the list?

```
typedef struct A_NewNumber {
   struct A_NewNumber *next;
   double newNum;
} NewNumber;   

void NumberSize(NewNumber *start){

    NewNumber *determine = start;
    double SecondNumber =0;
    double FirstNumber = 0;
    while(determine){
        //the number from the current node
        FirstNumber = determine->newNum;
        SecondNuumber = next->newNum;

        if(FirstNumber < SecondNumber){
            printf("The biggest number is:\n", SecondNumber);
        }else{
            printf("The smallest number is:\n", FirstNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `newNum` in next node using `determine->next->newNum` and change your `while` loop this way:

```
while(determine->next != NULL){
    //the number from the current node
    FirstNumber = determine->newNum;
    SecondNuumber = determine -> next->newNum;

    if(FirstNumber < SecondNumber){
       printf("The biggest number is:%lf\n", SecondNumber);
       printf("The smallest number is:%lf\n", FirstNumber);
    }else{
       printf("The biggest number is:%lf\n", FirstNumber);
       printf("The smallest number is:%lf\n", SecondNumber);
    }

    determine = determine -> next;//to traverse along the list
}
```

- Providing `determine = determine -> next;` at the end is essential to traverse or move along the linked list if not you'd be stuck at the same place and that'd make your loop an infinite loop
- and you forgot to mention format specifiers in your `printf()`

Answer (score 1):

To access the second number in the list, you'll need a pointer to that, which should be the `next` pointer of the first node. In your code, `next` is not defined. It should be something like this:

```
FirstNumber = determine->newNum;
SecondNumber = determine->next->newNum;
```

Also, you didn't provide the definition of `NewNumber`. It would be clearer if the definition was posted in the question.

Comment: i have add the NewNumber definition

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
typedef struct a_node
{
    struct a_node* next;
    double n;
}Node;

void numberSize(Node* dList)
{
    if(dList == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    Node* current = dList;
    double a, b;

    while(current->next != NULL)
    {
        a = current->n;
        b = current->next->n;

        // your message.

        current = current->next;
    }
}
```